# convertir de /Date(1637647200000)/ epoch a fecha YYYY/MM/DD con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, datatables, asp.net-mvc-5

Hola buen día tengo una lista que me trae una fecha de la base de datos a mi controlador ASP.Net

```
public JsonResult ListaFacturas()
{
    var Lista = db.Eq_tblFacturas.Select(a => new
    {
        a.id,
        a.NoPedido,
        Fecha = a.Fecha,
        provedores = a.Seg_tblProveedores.Nombre,
    }).ToArray();

    
    return Json(Lista, "application/json");

}
```

y en mi vista llega así:

```
<table id="table"
       data-toggle="table"
       data-method="post"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-pagination-loop="false"
       data-search="true"
       data-remember-order="true"
       data-url="@Url.Action("ListaFacturas","Facturas")"
       data-toolbar=".Group-btn"
       data-click-to-select="true"
       data-id-field="id"
       data-select-item-name="id" class="table-Index">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-radio="true"></th>
            <th data-field="id">Id</th>
            <th data-field="NoPedido">No.Pedido</th>
            <th data-field="Fecha" >Fecha</th>
            <th data-field="provedores">Provedores</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

en la vista me muestra la fecha de la siguiente manera /Date(1637647200000)/
investigando aprendí que es formato epoch UNIX y se puede formatear pero no eh logrado hacerlo intente con JavaScript de la siguiente manera:

```
function Fecha(value) {

    
    
    var fechaNum = value.slice(6, -2);

    var fecha = new Date(Number(fechaNum));

    var yyyy = fecha.getFullYear();
    var mm = mes(fecha.getMonth());
    var dd = Formato(fecha.getDate());
    return dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy;
}
```

al hacer esto la pagina solo se queda cargando y no pasa de ahi
con el siguiente error: en consola **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'slice')**

espero alguien pueda ayudarme a resolver esto

Comment: ¿No sería mejor hacer la conversión en tu controlador? No sé qué tipo de base de datos consultas ni el ORM que usas (o no) pero seguramente habrá una forma de expresar la fecha en el formato que necesitas desde el mismo controlador antes de devolver el resultado al cliente. Es lo que se me ocurre ahora. Saludos

Comment: En mi controlador si llega como formato fecha pero en mi vista se convierte en epoch me imagino por el datatable la base de datos es SQL Server y mi ORM es el Entity Framework

Comment: De igual manera me diste una idea, desde mi controlador al crear la lista la mande como un string  `Fecha = a.Fecha.ToString()` y eso resolvio el problema aun asi me sigue intrigando el tema de por que mi javascript no funciona ya que no me reconoce instrucciones como `slice()` o `match()`

Answer (score -2):

Había encontrado en google como hacerlo,
pero acabo de ver que en stackoverflow ya lo habían preguntado
[Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

En ese hilo te dan respuestas con formatos mas o menos largos a como convertirlo, por ejemplo

```
var s = new Date(1504095567183).toLocaleDateString("en-US")
console.log(s) 
// expected output "8/30/2017"
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta. Debe expicar su respuesta. Este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, pero  es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y si desea ofrecer el enlace como referencia. Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. Puede revisar como [escribir una buena respuesta.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) .

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).